# Select2 appending and removing option groups and options

Tags: jquery, dropdown, jquery-select2, html-select

I'm trying to create a dynamic select2 dropdown, with an option group and options. The option group needs to have a dynamic number of options in it.

The problem I have is how to remove an option group and all of it's options, re-append that same option group with the same label and id, but now with different options in jquery.

This is the function i call on every change, when the option group's options are supposed to get changed:

```
function EmptyDropDowns() {
    $("[id$=ddlOfficeAccount] optgroup").remove();
    $("[id$=ddlOfficeAccount]").append('<optgroup id="Offices" label="Offices"></optgroup>');
    $("[id$=Offices]").append($("<option></option>").text("- All Offices -").val("0"));
}
```

and then later, fill the group option with the other options:

```
 if (Offices.length > 0) {
        for (var i in result.Offices) {
            $("[id$=Offices]").append($("<option></option>").text(result.Offices[i]).val(result.Offices[i]));
        }
    }
```

This works only the first time, creates a Select2 dropdown with an option group Offices, and accordingly X offices in it. But when a reload needs to happen, this code:

```
 $("[id$=ddlOfficeAccount] optgroup").remove();
 $("[id$=ddlOfficeAccount]").append('<optgroup id="Offices" label="Offices"></optgroup>');
```

Re-apends the same option group, even though it doesn't physically exist in the DOM anymore.

Is there anyway $("[id$=Offices]") can be cleared before it is re-appended? I need it to be the same element(same id) as I later check the group option as the parent of the chosen option.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to explicitly destroy select2 element and then re-register it.
$('#mySelect2').select2('destroy');